# Call asp.net web service from PHP with multiple parameters with authetication

Tags: php

I am trying to call asp.net webservice using php soap client. but not succeed.
Following is asp code to run web service which execute properly.

```
 BASWebService webService = new BASWebService();

                XmlDocument objInput = new XmlDocument();

                objInput.Load(Server.MapPath("FuelDetails.xml"));



                AuthenticationHeader authentication = new AuthenticationHeader();



                authentication.Username = "LTAMSEDI";

                authentication.Password = "LT@2015AMS";

                authentication.strVendorCode = "V0021240";



                string dsData1 = webService.GetEquipmentFuelData(objInput, authentication);
```

But how could I use in php my php code is :

```
$data1 = file_get_contents('test_xml.xml');
$client = new SoapClient('https://net.lntecc.com/cms/services/BAS/BASWebService.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1,'exceptions' => 0));
$ret = $client->GetEquipmentFuelData($data1, array('classmap' => array(
  'AuthenticationHeader' => array('Username'=>'LTAMSEDI', 'Password'=>'LT@2015AMS', 'strVendorCode' => 'V0021240')
)));

var_dump($ret);
```

Thanks in advance .....

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: I am not able to send data properly. Api need two parameter first is xml data and second is authentication parameter. How can I send?

Comment: Where is the problem? Do you get an error message? What does the var_dump show?

Comment: Server was unable to process request. ---> System Error! please contact helpdesk, Error Code is : 3982072